# Multiple linear regression for multiple columns (one at a time) in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression, multiple-columns

I have a dataset with columns representing wavenumbers along with weight.
A sample dataset is given below and the actual dataset has almost 3000+ columns related to different wavenumbers.
I want to perform a multiple linear regression for each wavenumber (weight as the independent variable and each wavenumber at a time as the dependent variable) and obtain the R^2 values for each wavenumber. The objective is to identify the most important wavenumbers based on these R^2 values

For example, the linear regression model for 1st wavenumber will be:

X400 ~ weight
X401 ~ weight etc...

I want to create a loop to obtain the R^2 values for each wavenumber and store it in a separate table to use in further analysis.

I used the below code to build a linear model for 1 wavenumber. But I don't understand to create a loop for each column as the original dataset has 3000+ wavenumbers.

```
  df1 = data.frame(
  weight = c(15, 18, 20, 21, 18),
  X400 = c(12.5, 9, 16.5, 9, 20),
  X401 = c(12, 19, 14.5, 9, 26),
  X402 = c(11.5, 9.6, 18.5, 19, 20),
  X403 = c(10.5, 8, 12.5, 17, 23),
  X404 = c(12.5, 9, 15, 9, 20),
  X405 = c(14.5, 19, 12.5, 8, 21.2),
  X406 = c(13.5, 7, 18.5, 12, 17),
  X407 = c(12, 3.9, 12.9, 10, 4.8))

  model <- lm(X400 ~ weight, data = df1)
  summary(model)$r.squared
```

The output table should look like this. R1, R2, R3,... represents the R^2 values related to each wavenumber.

| Wavenumber | R^2 value |
| --- | --- |
| X400 | R1 |
| X401 | R2 |
| X402 | R3 |
| X403 | R4 |
| X404 | R5 |
| X405 | R6 |
| X406 | R7 |
| X407 | R8 |

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Something like this will get the values: `sapply(names(df1)[-1], function(var) summary(lm(paste(var,"~weight"), df1))$r.squared)`

Comment: The response vectors can be arranged as a matrix on the LHS: `models <- lm(as.matrix(df1[-1]) ~ weight, df1);
  models |>
    summary() |>
    sapply(function(x) x$r.squared) |>
    stack() |>
    setNames(c("R2", "Response")) |>
    rev() |>
    transform(Response = sub(".* ", "", Response))`  Everything from stack onwards is just to make it a data frame with nice names and can be omitted if that is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 = data.frame(
  weight = c(15, 18, 20, 21, 18),
  X400 = c(12.5, 9, 16.5, 9, 20),
  X401 = c(12, 19, 14.5, 9, 26),
  X402 = c(11.5, 9.6, 18.5, 19, 20),
  X403 = c(10.5, 8, 12.5, 17, 23),
  X404 = c(12.5, 9, 15, 9, 20),
  X405 = c(14.5, 19, 12.5, 8, 21.2),
  X406 = c(13.5, 7, 18.5, 12, 17),
  X407 = c(12, 3.9, 12.9, 10, 4.8))

df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-weight, names_to="vbl", values_to = "vals") %>% 
  group_by(vbl) %>% 
  summarise(r2 = summary(lm(vals ~ weight))$r.squared)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 2
#>   vbl        r2
#>   <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 X400  0.00941
#> 2 X401  0.0398 
#> 3 X402  0.403  
#> 4 X403  0.0871 
#> 5 X404  0.0249 
#> 6 X405  0.259  
#> 7 X406  0.0162 
#> 8 X407  0.00384
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>